# Geometry Nodes - Partially filled curve

Tags: geometry-nodes, fcurves

Do you know a way to fill a user-specified part of a curve that is part of one object?
I have included it in the screenshot below, hope it will be understandable.
Thanks for the suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have two curves as one object, and you want to work on only one of them with `Fill Curve`, but not the other one.

If I am correct in my assumption, you can achieve this by separating the objects.

For this you only need a selection, which you create depending on the spline index.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solutions are the hardest to come up with, thank you :)